# Sometimes UI not change when property changed

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have this XAML code in my project :

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="favorite"
                          Click="AppBarButton_Click">
                <AppBarButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                              Name="appFontIcon"
                              Glyph="&#xE0A5;" />
                </AppBarButton.Icon>
            </AppBarButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The Click event for AppBarButton is this:

```
private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (appFontIcon.Glyph == "\xE0A5")
    {
        appFontIcon.Glyph = "\xE006";
    }
    else
        appFontIcon.Glyph = "\xE0A5";            
}
```

When I click AppBarButton, the **Glyph property** always changes, but on the user interface, sometimes the Icon changes, and sometimes it doesn't. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Glyph property always change, there is no problem. When the Glyph property didn't change ?

Comment: My mean is Property work good, but UI not work like property. I think I should force refresh UI but don't know how.

Comment: I tested your code, and the Glyph property always change in the UI. provide screenshots please .

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1GrwabO my test project, it still bug.

Comment: I will edit the post because using AppBarButton inside <Page.BottomAppBar> tag will cause the problem, outside BottomAppBar it will work without any problem, and please find the solution below .

Comment: Thank you. I'll take that as a temporary solution before find a better solution. I just want it look like "favorite button" in Picture Hub in-built OS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [AppBarToggleButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbartogglebutton) to achieve what you want .

Try this `without the code behind` :

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
            <AppBarToggleButton  Label="favorite">
                <AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
                    <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
                              Name="appFontIcon"
                              Glyph="&#xE0A5;" />
                </AppBarToggleButton.Icon>
            </AppBarToggleButton>
        </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```